# What is the best free OR proprietary DAW running on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, jack, daw

I spend about 10-12 hours a day on LMMS, but frankly it's a bit clunky and it crashes a lot.  I'm ready, if necessary, to shell out a bit of money (as little as possible) for a TRULY graceful and powerful DAW.  It would need to be a full-blown affair with extensive VSTs and samples, built-in MIDI interface, etc.  I have the Scarlett Focusrite 3, Gen 2 running the Samson Carbon 49 so I'm not sure interface is the proper term.  The software would need to support it is what I mean.  I would prefer one that ran Alsa AND Jack and had extensive expansion packs available.  Due to my budget I can't go over $300 to $400 to start.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 400 is more then 300, so you certainly can go over it. :~)

Comment: Point made and taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best one I've come across is [Ardour](https://ardour.org/), which is also part of the Ubuntu Studio distribution.

Then there's [Reaper](https://www.reaper.fm/), but that only has an "experimental" Linux build, so no idea how well that is running.

Answer (score 0):

[Harrison Mixbus](https://harrisonconsoles.com/site/mixbus.html) not free, but Harrison do good discount offers so well within your budget

Demo version of Mixbus, and lots more including Ardour, is included with AVLinux, which is similar to Ubuntu Studio but Debian based

Answer (score 0):

Bitwig Studio is a professional and proprietary DAW that runs native on Ubuntu Linux. It is very similar to Ableton Live, but has some different features and a very powerful modulation system that can be used all throughout. I highly recommend looking into it:

https://www.bitwig.com/en/home.html